# Py2app not working with random math module

Tags: python, math, random, py2app

If I run the command:

```
python setup.py py2app
```

Then, I run my application, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jmeyer2k/Desktop/PixelBuild/Development/dist/PixelBuild.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 31, in <module>
    _run('PixelBuild.py')
  File "/Users/jmeyer2k/Desktop/PixelBuild/Development/dist/PixelBuild.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 28, in _run
    execfile(path, globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/jmeyer2k/Desktop/PixelBuild/Development/dist/PixelBuild.app/Contents/Resources/PixelBuild.py", line 7, in <module>
    import random
  File "/Users/jmeyer2k/Desktop/PixelBuild/Development/dist/PixelBuild.app/Contents/Resources/random.py", line 45, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
ImportError: cannot import name log
```

I am assuming it has something to do with the random module and the math module. My first thought was to include the math module in the data files, but I tried it and it still didn't work. I may not be including the right file. I included: `math.so`. Please help.

Comment: Do you named one of your modules random.py, maybe? That would be a really BAD idea.